# Iterate vector element object

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a newbie coder.

Can anyone teach me how to get the value inside storedVector[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZKA3.png)[3] ? I tried a lot of ways but i can only loop through storedVector and not the value inside the storedVector object

EDIT:

tableData.java

```
public class TableData {
     static Vector storedVector = new Vector();


   public void fillSortedData(File file, Vector data){ 
      Workbook workbook = null;
      Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
      int monthnow = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
  try {
      try {
          workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger( 
                  excelTojTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } 
      Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
      headers.clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
          Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(i, 0);
       headers.add(cell1.getContents()); }
  data.clear();
  for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) { 
      Vector d = new Vector();
      for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) { 
          Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j); 
          d.add(cell.getContents()); 

          CellType type = cell.getType();
          if(type == CellType.DATE){
              String cellDateStr = cell.getContents();
              DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
              try {
                  Date cellDate = formatter.parse(cellDateStr);
                  int month = cellDate.getMonth() + 1;
                  if(monthnow != month) {
                      d.clear();
                      //d.removeAllElemen8ts();
                      i = sheet.getColumns();
                  }
              } catch (ParseException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
          }
      } 
      if(d.isEmpty() == false) {
          d.add("\n");  
          data.add(d);
          storedVector.add(d);
      }
  } 
  } catch (BiffException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
}
  public void emailList() {
  int abc = storedVector.size();
//iterate through the vector and get all the element

  }
}   
 }
```

I created a vector "data" using the same method as storedVector in another java class.

In tableData.java, I wanted to create a method "emaillist" that can iterate and get all the email that was show in the picture and save it in a list or array

[image: Image of my problem that i want to iterate]

Comment: Show us how `storedVector` is declared to let us know the exact type of it

Comment: I add the java class that i am working on. Not sure if it will helps. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

if `storedVector` is a list/set of `Vector`, this code can help:

```
    for(Vector vector: storedVector){
       for(int i=0; i< vector.size(); i++){  
        //access to vector[i] 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vector extends AbstractList. So it should have a Vector.get(i) method.

Try using

```
Vector v = storedVector.get(1);
Object o = v.get(3);
```